# rest api path design questions

Tags: api, rest, lumen

Im designing an API and have countered some issues, or more like questions regarding good/best practices on designing the API.

I'm returning **missions** available in the system, and a mission has a relation to a **employer**.

```
v1/missions // Returns all available missions.
v1/employer/1/missions // Returns all missions created by an employer.
```

But lets say that a **person** now wants to book a mission he finds interesting.

```
v1/missions/2?booking=true
v1/employer/1/missions/2?booking=true
```

I could use first method since it's much cleaner and simpler. I don't have to care about ids either since I already know them from the response.

The second method looks better since I'd know which employer and mission the booking would have.

Either way, I'll have to maintain these 2 routes now. And the annoying part is that questions regarding stuff like this is popping up in my head all the time when splitting up routes that behave almost the same way as the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, what do you think about something like below:

```
GET    /employers/{employerId}/missions/{missionId}    Check if an employer has mission booked.
PUT    /employers/{employerId}/missions/{missionId}    Add a mission to the employer (create a booking)
DELETE /employers/{employerId}/missions/{missionId}    Remove a mission from the employer (cancel booking)
```

Or

```
GET  /employers/{employerId}/missions/{missionId}/booked   Check if an employer has mission booked.
PUT  /employers/{employerId}/missions/{missionId}/booked   Put "true" to book. Put "false" to cancel booking.
```

If above doesn't suit your use case or your application has a more complicated relations, you may think about making `bookings` a resource:

- Get a booking (or check if it exists)

  ```
  GET  /bookings/{bookingId}
  ```
- Create a booking:

  ```
  POST  /bookings/   { "employerId": 1; "missionId": 2}
  ```
- Cancel a booking

  ```
  DELETE  /bookings/{bookingId}
  ```

Designing REST API is usually tricky and sometimes (especially at the beginning) requires a change the way we think.

Comment: Thank you!
I think I'll go with numero dos to start with. And use bookings as a resource if everything goes down the slope to hell.